# using a Solr function in the query itself

Tags: solr

The FunctionQuery [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) explain how to use the function syntax for sorting and boosting, but I'm still not clear on how to use functions in the query itself.  As a trivial example, instead of

```
q=price[2 TO 4]
```

I'd like to do something to the effect of

```
q=price[2 TO sum(3,1)]
```

but I don't understand how to structure the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

> fq={!frange **l**=0 **u**=2.2} sum(Field1,Field2)

`l` is The lower bound

`u` is The Uper bound

Solr cwiki here. [Function Range Query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser)

Comment: This syntax works with a caveat, with a USD currency field I had to specify the range endpoints in cents rather than dollars.  So `q=price:[2 TO 4]` is equivalent to `fq={!frange l=200 u=400} price`.

Comment: USD currency field type?sort.CurrencyField?

Comment: if the fieldtype is sort.CurrencyField,you should use `price:[* TO 10.00,USD]`  [CurrencyField Query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CurrencyField#Querying)